# PHP ARRAY with Key as timestamp & Merging Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, merge

I would like to build an Array having the Key as timestamp, and for some reason it works when I build it manually, but it doesn't work when I try to Merge a new item.

I read the fastest way to merge is with: array[] but it adds an index [0],[1] in front of the key, I would need to find a work around this, too. Since I need to access the key by timestamp.

```
$timeStamp=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

$maxCapArray=array();

// IDEAL MERGING BUT NOT WORKING: $maxCapArray[]= $timeStamp => array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLOBLO');

// (string) NOT WORKING: $maxCapArray[]= (string)$timeStamp => array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLUBLU');

$maxCapArray = array($timeStamp => array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLEBLE')); $maxCapArray = array($timeStamp => array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLIBLI'));

// MANUALLY ONLY TAKES THE LAST ITEM:

echo $maxCapArray[$timeStamp]['Author'];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't quite understand. What is the input data you have? What is the output data you want?

Comment: why is `$maxCapArray` being defined twice on the same line? The second definition will override the first, so it's no wonder you're only getting the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add elements like `$maxCapArray[]= $timeStamp => array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLOBLO');`.

- You can do this:

  $v=array();
   $v[]=array("a"=>array(1,2,3));

which will get:

```
print_r($v);
Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) ) )
```

- or this:

  $v["a"]=array(1,2,3);

which will get:

```
print_r($v);
Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) )
```

Comment: Hi Fedorqui, 
I did this: $v[$timeStamp]=array(1,2,3); and tried to echo it manually like this: echo $v[$timestamp][0], and tried also $timestamp, '$timestamp', string($timestamp), strval($timestamp)
but doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: This should work: `$timestamp="aaaa";
$v[$timestamp]=array(1,2,3); 
print_r($v);
echo "hi this is ". $v[$timestamp][0];`. The thing is that you have to keep the index `$timestamp`. If $timestamp is defined again, you will not be able to access to it. Hence, use `print_r($v)` to check how the array has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what the structure you'd end up needed.

I think you may need something like this:

```
<?php

// initial an empty array
$maxCapArray=array();

// first run on a day
$timeStampA=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
$maxCapArray[$timestampA] = array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLEBLE');

// second run on a different day
$timeStampB=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
$maxCapArray[$timestampB] = array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLEBLE');

// third run on yet another day
$timeStampC=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
$maxCapArray[$timestampC] = array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLEBLE');

// ...

// to retrieve the Author of a given timestamp
echo $maxCapArray[$timestampA]['Author'];
echo $maxCapArray[$timestampB]['Author'];
echo $maxCapArray[$timestampC]['Author'];

?>
```

The first line will remove all data you get previously. Please use them in a logical way.

Another guess:

```
<?php

// initial an empty array
$maxCapArray=array();
$timeStamp=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

// suppose you want $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Book'] and $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['author']
// to be arrays
if (!isset($maxCapArray[$timestamp])) $maxCapArray[$timestamp] = array();
$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Book'][]   = 'BLABLA';
$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author'][] = 'BLEBLE';

$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Book'][]   = 'BLABLA 2';
$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author'][] = 'BLEBLE 2';

// ...

// you should get an array:
var_dump($maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author']);

?>
```

**Update: It seems you're looking for this**

```
<?php

// initial an empty array
$maxCapArray=array();
$timeStamp=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

// suppose you want $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Book'] and $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['author']
// to be arrays
if (!isset($maxCapArray[$timestamp])) $maxCapArray[$timestamp] = array();
$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author']['Book 1'] = 'Author 1';
$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author']['Book 2'] = 'Author 2';
$maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author']['Book 3'] = 'Author 2';

// ...

// review your array:
var_dump($maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author']);

// retrieve
$author_name = 'Author A';
$book_name = 'Book 1';
echo $maxCapArray[$timestamp][$author_name][$book_name];

?>
```

**Some more advice**

An array only do an index structure for 1 specific situation. And some days later, you may need another. Perhaps you'd need to search author by book, or search timestamp by book. Who knows?

I'd suggest you to use relational database for these case. You may create a database table in MySQL, like this:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| record_id | author              | book                                     | timestamp           |
+-----------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 1         | Jules Verne         | Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea    | 2013-01-12 12:24:00 |
| 2         | Jules Verne         | Journey to the Center of the Earth       | 2013-01-12 13:01:00 |
| 3         | William Shakespeare | Hamlet                                   | 2013-01-12 16:51:00 |
+-----------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

MySQL will automatically do all the indexing works.

Then when you needed the data, you can connect to the database and read:

```
<?php

// connect to 
mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password');
mysql_select_db('library_database');

// ask database of books of a certain timestamp and of certain author
$results = mysql_query('SELECT author FROM book_records WHERE 
  timestamp="2013-01-12 13:01:00" AND book="Journey to the Center of the Earth"');

// read the database's answer to $books array
$authors = array();
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) != FALSE) {
  $authors = $row['author'];
}

// you may examine the array here
// this is a list of author of the specific timestamp
// and of specific book
var_dump($authors);

?>
```

And if you have another need, you can just change the code:

```
<?php

// connect to 
mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password');
mysql_select_db('library_database');


// if you want to have all the timestamp of a book and an author
// you may just do this
$results = mysql_query('SELECT timestamp FROM book_records WHERE 
  author="Jules Verne" AND book="Journey to the Center of the Earth"');


// read the database's answer to $books array
$timestamps = array();
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) != FALSE) {
  $timestamps = $row['timestamp'];
}

// this is the list of related timestamp
var_dump($timestamps);

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Koala, Version 2 is closer to what I want.


Now is more clear how to create the array. 


But to retrieve it, I have $timestamp & $Book, and I'd like to get
Author. How do I need to call the array?


// this gives Author but I need to know the correct index number, which I don't have


    echo $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author'][0].'<BR>';
    echo $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author'][1].'<BR>';


It should be something like this:


    echo $maxCapArray[$timestamp]['Author'][$Book].'<BR>'; 


and should give -> Author for specific $timestamp & Book

Comment: Updated my answer. Please read the **Update** part. My recommendation would be using SQLite or MySQL database, thou. Please take a look at my example. If you find it useful, go and search the internet for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
$timeStamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
$maxCapArray = array();

$maxCapArray[$timeStamp] = array();
$maxCapArray[$timeStamp][] = array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLEBLE');
$maxCapArray[$timeStamp][] = array('Book'=>'BLABLA','Author'=>'BLIBLI');

echo $maxCapArray[$timeStamp][0]['Author']; // == BLEBLE
```

be warned that if you use `array_merge()` to merge numerically indexed arrays, the keys will be reindexed starting from zero, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php